# What does "twist" mean in film criticism?

Tags: terminology

A critic says about [LEFT BEHIND](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/left_behind_2014)

> It believes people might buy a ticket to Left Behind and not know the **twist**, like someone sitting down to watch Godzilla and being shocked by the entrance of a giant lizard.

What does "twist" mean there? Does it refer to some part of the movie or something else out of the movie?

Comment: This strikes me as more of an English language comprehension question.

Comment: You expect something, but in the middle or at the end, story goes a whole different path which you clearly had no idea it would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s short for “plot twist”. Although there is no plot twist in either movie. Just a main event or plot device that should be assumed from the title. Just like the movies Titanic, Lincoln, or Passion of the Christ. The “critic“ you are quoting is using sarcasm to state that there is no twist. They could have used the term “spoiler” instead.

But, I can not put too much stock in the logic or taste of the reviews listed on the site to which you linked. One reviewer actually Complained about the “ Overt Christian messages”. This is a Christian movie from Christian producers and directors which is a direct remake of another quite famous Christian movie. What exactly was this reviewer expecting? Even if he had never read the Bible or gone to a church service in his entire life, did he really need a spoiler alert before going to see this movie? I, like the critic in your question, can’t believe people can be that thick. Just say why you did not like the movie instead of pretending you were somehow tricked into seeing it.